# How to group by date and ID using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create a .csv file using XSLT 1.0 where I want to be able to group both by ID and date.

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><RunPeriod PeriodStart="01102019"  PeriodEnd="02102019"><Employees>

<ID WageCode="2250"><Name>John Doe</Name><Date>01-10-2019</Date><Starttime>08:30</Starttime><Endtime>12:00</Endtime><Absence></Absence><PublicHoliday>0</PublicHoliday><OvertimeStart>08:30</OvertimeStart><OvertimeEnd>12:00</OvertimeEnd></ID>
<DatesAndWeekdays><Dates>01-10-2019</Dates><NameOfWeekday>Tuesday</NameOfWeekday></DatesAndWeekdays>
<ID WageCode="1857"><Name>Jane Doe</Name><Date>01-10-2019</Date><Starttime>09:45</Starttime><Endtime>12:45</Endtime><Absence></Absence><PublicHoliday>0</PublicHoliday><OvertimeStart>09:45</OvertimeStart><OvertimeEnd>12:45</OvertimeEnd></ID>
<DatesAndWeekdays><Dates>01-10-2019</Dates><NameOfWeekday>Tuesday</NameOfWeekday></DatesAndWeekdays>
<ID WageCode="2250"><Name>John Doe</Name><Date>01-10-2019</Date><Starttime>13:15</Starttime><Endtime>16:00</Endtime><Absence></Absence><PublicHoliday>0</PublicHoliday><OvertimeStart>13:15</OvertimeStart><OvertimeEnd>16:00</OvertimeEnd></ID>
<DatesAndWeekdays><Dates>01-10-2019</Dates><NameOfWeekday>Tuesday</NameOfWeekday></DatesAndWeekdays>
<ID WageCode="1857"><Name>Jane Doe</Name><Date>01-10-2019</Date><Starttime>14:45</Starttime><Endtime>17:30</Endtime><Absence></Absence><PublicHoliday>0</PublicHoliday><OvertimeStart>14:45</OvertimeStart><OvertimeEnd>17:30</OvertimeEnd></ID>
<DatesAndWeekdays><Dates>01-10-2019</Dates><NameOfWeekday>Tuesday</NameOfWeekday></DatesAndWeekdays>
<ID WageCode="2250"><Name>John Doe</Name><Date>01-10-2019</Date><Starttime>17:30</Starttime><Endtime>20:30</Endtime><Absence></Absence><PublicHoliday>0</PublicHoliday><OvertimeStart>17:30</OvertimeStart><OvertimeEnd>20:30</OvertimeEnd></ID>
<DatesAndWeekdays><Dates>01-10-2019</Dates><NameOfWeekday>Tuesday</NameOfWeekday></DatesAndWeekdays>
<ID WageCode="2250"><Name>John Doe</Name><Date>02-10-2019</Date><Starttime>08:15</Starttime><Endtime>18:00</Endtime><Absence></Absence><PublicHoliday>0</PublicHoliday><OvertimeStart>08:15</OvertimeStart><OvertimeEnd>18:00</OvertimeEnd></ID>
<DatesAndWeekdays><Dates>02-10-2019</Dates><NameOfWeekday>Wednesday</NameOfWeekday></DatesAndWeekdays>
<ID WageCode="1857"><Name>Jane Doe</Name><Date>02-10-2019</Date><Starttime>08:45</Starttime><Endtime>17:30</Endtime><Absence></Absence><PublicHoliday>0</PublicHoliday><OvertimeStart>08:45</OvertimeStart><OvertimeEnd>17:30</OvertimeEnd></ID>
<DatesAndWeekdays><Dates>02-10-2019</Dates><NameOfWeekday>Wednesday</NameOfWeekday></DatesAndWeekdays>
</Employees></RunPeriod>
```

Where my two subjects have working times Tuesday and Wednesday. So far I have been able to group them based on their ID, so I get one row each for one day using the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="grpEmployee" match="ID" use="@WageCode"/>
    <xsl:key name="grpDay" match="DatesAndWeekdays" use="Dates"/>
    <xsl:variable name="startDate"  select="RunPeriod/@PeriodStart"/>
    <xsl:variable name="endDate" select="RunPeriod/@PeriodEnd"/>

    <xsl:template match="Employees">
        <xsl:text>Employee name</xsl:text> <!--> Add first column employee name -->
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <!--> Add the dates from the export period - PeriodStart and PeriodEnd -->
        <xsl:call-template name="DateList">
            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="number(substring($startDate, 1, 2))" />
            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="number(substring($startDate, 3, 2))" />
            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="number(substring($startDate, 5))" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <!--> Add employee data-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ID[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('grpEmployee',@WageCode)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('grpEmployee', @WageCode)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Absence = 'Annual leave'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Absence"/>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="PublicHoliday = '1'">
                    <xsl:text>Public Holiday</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="Starttime = '00:00' and Endtime = '00:00'">
                    <xsl:text>Day off</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Starttime"/>
                    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Endtime"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>

        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="DateList">
        <xsl:param name="day" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="month" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="year" select="1" />
        <xsl:variable name="validationResult">
            <xsl:call-template name="date-is-valid">
                <xsl:with-param name="day" select="$day"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$year"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$validationResult = 0">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$month &gt; 12">           
                        <xsl:call-template name="DateList">
                            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="1" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="1" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$year + 1" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="DateList">
                            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="1" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month + 1" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$year" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>                                                
                <xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="concat(format-number($day, '00'), format-number($month, '00'), $year)" />

                <xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'-',$month,'-',$year)" />
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>

                <xsl:if test="not($currentDate = $endDate)">
                    <xsl:call-template name="DateList">
                        <xsl:with-param name="day" select="$day + 1" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$year" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="date-is-valid">
        <xsl:param name="year" select="''"/>
        <xsl:param name="month" select="''"/>
        <xsl:param name="day" select="''"/>

        <xsl:variable name="year-is-integer" select="number($year) = $year and floor($year) = $year" />
        <xsl:variable name="month-is-integer" select="number($month) = $month and floor($month) = $month" />
        <xsl:variable name="day-is-integer" select="number($day) = $day and floor($day) = $day" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="
                    not($year-is-integer) or not($month-is-integer) or not($day-is-integer) or
                    $month &lt; 1 or $month &gt; 12 or
                    $day &lt; 1 or $day &gt; 31 or (
                    ($year mod 4 = 0 and $month = 2 and $day &gt; 29) or
                    ($year mod 4 != 0 and $month = 2 and $day &gt; 28) or
                    (($month = 4 or $month = 6 or $month = 9 or $month = 11) and $day &gt; 30))">
                <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

expected output:

```
Employee name     Tuesday                                Wednesday  
                 01-10-2019                             02-10-2019  
John Doe    08:30-12:00 13:15-16:00 17:30-20:00         08:15-18:00 
Jane Doe    09:45-12:45 14:45-17:30                     08:45-17:30
```

actual output:

```
Employee name    Tuesday             Wednesday      
                 01-10-2019          02-10-2019     
John Doe         08:30-12:00         13:15-16:00    17:30-20:30 08:15-18:00
Jane Doe         09:45-12:45         14:45-17:30    08:45-17:30
```

If my subjects has multiple working times on a day, I want all the working times to be shown on that day. The code works fine if they have just one working time e.g. 08:15-18:00, but cannot handle multiple working times on a day.

How do I make the working times correspond to their respective date?

Comment: Where is the relevant date data to group by, just in that `Date` child of each `ID` you already group? Or are those `DatesAndWeekdays` also relevant. For second level grouping using XSLT 1 and Muenchian grouping you usually solve that with a second key incorporating the first level key e.g. `<xsl:key name="group-id-and-date" match="ID" use="concat(@WageCode, '|', Date)"/>` and then you use e.g. `$first-level-group[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-id-and-date', concat(@WageCode, '|', Date))[1]]` to identify the subgroups.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
DatesAndWeekdays is used to get the names of the weekdays. The relevant date data is the 'Date' child.
Should I replace the "grpEmployee" key with the key you have provided? And should I also use that key in the for-each loop? Or do I need a second for-each loop with that key?

Comment: No, you don't replace the first level key with the second level one, you start with the first level key to (in your case) group by and output based on that first level, then, instead of processing `key('grpEmployee', @WageCode)` (with `for-each` or `apply-templates`) you process `key('grpEmployee', @WageCode)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-id-and-date', concat(@WageCode, '|', Date)))[1]]` to group each first level group by the second level key.

Comment: See also https://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200101/msg00070.html.

Comment: Okay so far I added `<xsl:variable name="first-level-group" select="key('grpEmployee', @WageCode)"/>` as a global variable and I added `<xsl:apply-templates select="$first-level-group[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-id-and-date', concat(@WageCode, '|', Date))[1])]"/>` and `<xsl:for-each select="$first-level-group[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-id-and-date', concat(@WageCode, '|', Date))[1])]"> `

Comment: But the employees and their working times are not getting extracted, I only get the get date - I also followed the link you sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the key from the comment

```
<xsl:key name="group-id-and-date" match="ID" use="concat(@WageCode, '|', Date)"/>
```

and then rewrote some templates to

```
<xsl:template match="ID">
    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('grpEmployee', @WageCode)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-id-and-date', concat(@WageCode, '|', Date))[1])]" mode="dates"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ID" mode="dates">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">; </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group-id-and-date', concat(@WageCode, '|', Date))" mode="date"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ID" mode="date">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Absence = 'Annual leave'">
                <xsl:value-of select="Absence"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="PublicHoliday = '1'">
                <xsl:text>Public Holiday</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="Starttime = '00:00' and Endtime = '00:00'">
                <xsl:text>Day off</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="Starttime"/>
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="Endtime"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamKS/2 then I think has the "right" "groups", you might need to adapt formatting/separators to your needs.